# How is it possible to view destructive interference reflected from a screen?

Tags: visible-light, interference

Imagine that 2 rays of light are made to converge in one point and interfere destructively there.
A sheet of paper is placed at that point (not a capture device), and the observer will look at the point on the sheet of paper.
What will the observer see ?

One would tend to say nothing because the rays cancel each other at that point, but on the other hand, there should be (diffuse) reflection so that the 2 rays will reflect in a diverging way (because they came at an angle) and not cancel each other after they bounce off the paper and reach the human eye, therefore showing light on the paper to the observer. So what happens ?

Comment: You seem to have answered your own question. If you put your eye at the screen itself, you will see nothing. If you put a piece of paper at the screen at then look at the piece of paper, you'll see something if your head is in the right place.

Comment: Destructive interference isn't at all like the annihilation of matter and antimatter, i.e. waves can't just 'cancel'. Whether interference between waves looks destructive or constructive depends on where you are.

Comment: there is a series of MIT opencourese videos that are instructive . try this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RRi4dv9KgCg&t=9s

Comment: @annav I posted this question just after seeing that very video. However my question is for beams that cancel each other in one point of the screen because they meet at an angle. That video is about beams that cancel each other everywhere becuse they are parralel and merged (moving the screen wont change the result)

Answer (score 1):

> [In optics a ray is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ray_(optics)) an idealized model of light, obtained by choosing a line that is perpendicular to the wavefronts of the actual light, and that points in the direction of energy flow.

...

> Ray theory (geometrical optics) does not describe phenomena such as *interference and diffraction*, which require wave theory (involving the relative phase of the rays).

italics mine

Two light beams are coherent if the phases  between the wave fronts are fixed, and that is why in n this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RRi4dv9KgCg&t=9s), two parallel beams by construction hit the screen and show an interference pattern. They are coherent because  mirrors and lenses are to used split an original coherent source into two beams, with known phases between the wavefronts, because mirrors and lenses do not destroy the coherence of a beam, that is why an image an be seen in a mirror.

So going back to the ray definition you are asking what happens to the interference patterns when the two wave-fronts meet at an angle. [This article](http://spie.org/samples/FG10.pdf) goes into details of two beam interference. I gather (page 5) that cos(Δφ) where φ is the angle between the two rays, controls the intensity in the spatial interference.

If the two beams are parallel, the difference in angle is zero, and  there is the  interference pattern seen in the video. An interference  pattern will appear as the cos(Δφ) between them goes to zero.

In this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RRi4dv9KgCg&t=9s) two parallel beams by construction hit the screen.

Τhere will be a background, the stronger the larger the difference in angle of meeting, not true  darkness until the beams hit parallel.

Now you clarify in the comments:

> My question relates to what happens when the fringe is observed on a screen by the human eye. My point is that if the 2 light rays come to the screen at an angle , they will bounce back at an angle too. After they bounce back they will interfere in space and therefore the eye should see different fringes on the screen depending on where the eye is. Is that interpretation correct ?

The fringe pattern observed at the screen in the video has no longer coherent radiation and thus no interference exists after the screen. The coherent light hitting the screen generates an enormous multitude of point sources, by scattering off the incoherent atoms and molecules of the surface and the lattice they form. It is only mirrors and mirror like surfaces which give off coherent scatters that can retain the coherence of the two incoming beams. So what the eye sees on the screen is at that (x,y) plane at a distance z from the source.

The experiment itself in the linked video uses mirrors extensively to manipulate the beams, but there is no loss of photons and the coherence is kept to appear as interference as the distances between optical elements change. Once the light hits the screen,( or the paper the instructor uses to point out the beam locations), that's it, coherence is lost in the reflected image. There can not be any fringe pattern in the intermediate region between the screen and the eye, just the fixed pattern of the screen is transmitted.

Comment: My question relates to what happens when the fringe is observed on a screen by the human eye. My point is that if the 2 light rays come to the screen at an angle , they will bounce back at an angle too. After they bounce back they will interfere in space and therefore the eye should see different fringes on the screen depending on where the eye is. Is that interpretation correct ?

Comment: OK. Lets get this clear. The coherent light from the laser in the video hits the screen and we see it. What we see is no longer a coherent set up, by hitting the screen  it desperses, it becomes a local source which hits our eye and we see the pattern on the screen the way our eyes see wherever they are focused. Only mirrors ( as in the video set up ) keep the beams coherent to keep on creating interference patterns in space, and a screen is not a mirror, it is a huge multitude of new point sources where the beams hit. Note that if it is mirror , you will be seeing the original laser source

Comment: in the video, and I would not advise to put your eye in the location of the paper the instructor uses.  So two laser beams at an angle will interfere less and have a bright background and they are coherent as long as they do not hit targets like screens. I will edit my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Please let me then ask further, why it is that in diffuse reflection (screen) we dont see anything where there is destructive interference, while in specular reflection (mirror) we can see something?

Comment: But we do see the interference fringes on the screen. The light coming from there is incoherent and will not interfere after the screen in a coherent way, but the individual pigments of the screen transmit the  light/dark. If you had a mirror where the screen is you would see the original interference at the plane of the (x,y) of your retina. I would not advise it. You will be directly seeing the source laser light as it is interfering in space, at the position of your eye.

Comment: I mean, why is it that no light is coming off from the screen dark fringe when light is coming off of the mirror where the dark fringe is located.
What is it with the dark fringe that prevents light from being reflected only in a screen and not a mirror